# Generate all possible customer and account combinations

Tags: algorithm, data-generation

I am developing an application to store the relationship data of customers and accounts (w.r.t banking domain). Typically in banks a customer can have an account which is a sole account or have a joint account with another customer.

Eg 1: Customer C1 has a sole account A1.
Eg 2: Customer C1 and C2 have a joint account JA1 where C1 is primary holder and C2 is non-primary holder.

I am looking for an algorithm that will generate all possible combinations of relationships for a given number of customers and accounts.

For example: if the number of customers = 2 and number of accounts = 2, then the algorithm should generate the below entries.

*Combination #1:*
C1-A1-Primary
C1-A2-Primary
C2-A1-Non-Primary
C2-A2-Non-Primary

*Combination #2:*
C1-A1-Primary
C1-A2-Non-Primary
C2-A1-Non-Primary
C2-A2-Primary

*Combination #3:*
C1-A1-Non-Primary
C1-A2-Primary
C2-A1-Primary
C2-A2-Non-Primary

*Combination #4:*
C1-A1-Non-Primary
C1-A2-Non-Primary
C2-A1-Primary
C2-A2-Primary

*Combination #5:*
C1-A1-Sole
C1-A2-Primary
C2-A2-Non-Primary

*Combination #6:*
C1-A1-Sole
C1-A2-Non-Primary
C2-A2-Primary

*Combination #7:*
C1-A2-Sole
C1-A1-Primary
C2-A1-Non-Primary

*Combination #8:*
C1-A2-Sole
C1-A1-Non-Primary
C2-A1-Primary

Edit: This is not the complete list of combinations - but the algorithm is supposed to generate all those.

Comment: There should be more? #9: C2-A1-Sole C1-A2-Primary C2-A2-Non-Primary... : 4 more combinations

Comment: Yes, I've not exhausted all the combinations. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems to solve here:

1. Get all possible account types for N customers. You can do it like this:

   const allAccounts = [];
   for (let i = 1; i <= customersNumber; i++) {
   allAccounts.push(`C${i}-Sole`);
   for (let j = 1; j <= customersNumber; j++) {
   if (i === j) continue;
   allAccounts.push(`C${i}-Primary C${j}-NonPrimary`);
   }
   }

For 2 customers the result will be:

```
[
  "C1-Sole",
  "C1-Primary C2-NonPrimary",
  "C2-Sole",
  "C2-Primary C1-NonPrimary"
]
```

2. Get all possible combinations of length r (with repetitions) from this array. We want to exclude two types of combinations here:

- ones that have 2 or more sole accounts for the same customer.
- ones that are not connected (have no common customers, if I got you right)

```js
// checks if two accounts are connected
function connected(customers1, customers2) {
    return customers1.filter(cu => customers2.includes(cu)).length > 0;
}

// checks if acc1 and acc2 are the same Sole account 
function sameSoleAccount(acc1, acc2) {
    return acc1.type === 'Sole' && acc1 === acc2;
}

function printAccount(i, a) {
    const c = a.customers;
    return a.type === 'Sole' ? `${c[0]}-A${i}-Sole` : `${c[0]}-A${i}-Primary ${c[1]}-A${i}-NonPrimary`;
}

function combination(chosen, arr, index, r) {
    if (index === r) {
        const combination = chosen.map((c, i) => printAccount(i + 1, arr[c])).join(', ');
        console.log(combination);
        return;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (chosen.length === 0 ||
            chosen.some(ch => !sameSoleAccount(arr[ch], arr[i])
                && connected(arr[ch].customers, arr[i].customers))) {
            const copy = chosen.slice();
            copy[index] = i;
            combination(copy, arr, index + 1, r);
        }
    }
}

function allPossibleCombinations(accountsNumber, customersNumber) {
    const allAccounts = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= customersNumber; i++) {
        allAccounts.push({customers: [`C${i}`], type: 'Sole'});
        for (let j = 1; j <= customersNumber; j++) {
            if (i === j) continue;
            allAccounts.push({customers: [`C${i}`, `C${j}`], type: 'Joint'});
        }
    }
    console.log(`All possible combinations for ${customersNumber} customers and ${accountsNumber} accounts: `);
    combination([], allAccounts, 0, accountsNumber);
}

allPossibleCombinations(2, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But could you please:

1) Bring in the context of account as well in the solution. For example: mentioning C1-Sole does not clearly imply whether it is for account A1 or A2.

2) All the accounts and customers should be part of the same graph. Meaning, you should be able to connect them all. C1-A1-Sole and C2-A2-Sole is valid, but they are not part of the same graph.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.

Comment: @veprmu you are welcome. If it worked for you, could you please mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: @Krill Simonov, I tried the code for 3,3 and the last line of the output was:
'C3-A1-Primary C2-A1-NonPrimary, C3-A2-Primary C2-A2-NonPrimary, C3-A3-Primary C2-A3-NonPrimary'

In this, I cannot see C1 in the graph.

Comment: @veprmu well, yes, this is how it works. There was no requirement that a combination should include all the customers. Moreover, there was no mention about any sort of graphs and connections in your original question at all. If you want some specific behavior then you need to describe it first. I suggest you to elaborate more on this part: *All the accounts and customers should be part of the same graph. Meaning, you should be able to connect them all.* E.g., what would you expect to see for 2 accounts and 4 customers?

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited relationship between accounts and customers:

1) create dict with:

```
dMapCustomer = {<nCustomerId>: [<nAccountId1>, <nAccountId2>]}
```

2) for each customer create all possible pairs, it is just

```
lCustomerPairs = [(nCustomerId, nAccountId1), (nCustomerId, nAccountId2), ...]
```

3) concat all pairs from step 2.

```
l = []
for nCustomer in lCustomer:
    l += lCustomerPairs
```

If any account can be linked with any customer, then just:

```
lAccounts = [1,2,3]
lCustomers = [4,5,6]
list(product(lCustomers, lCustomers)) # all possible pairs of account and customer
```

Function product generates all possible pairs from two lists:

```
def product(l1, l2): 
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in [l1, l2]] 
    result = [[]] 
    for pool in pools: 
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool] 
    for prod in result: 
        yield tuple(prod)
```